# Почему у меня не отображается моё загруженное фото в профиле?

Tags: поддержка, настройки-профиля

Зарегистрировался на сайте. Загрузил картинку в профиль.
Фото не отображается нигде, хотя я нажал кнопку "Сохранить"!
Что не так?

P.S.
Вот что вижу я:

[image: Это у меня]

А это у других:

[image: Так видят другие...]

Comment: Я вижу фотографию двух молодых людей в Вашем профиле и под этим вопросом.

Comment: Странно... А почему я не вижу?

Comment: Попробуйте нажать Ctrl+F5 - forced refresh.

Comment: Не помогает! (У меня Chromebook)

Comment: Есть ещё вариант, что в вашей сети почему-то забанен сайт imgur, на котором реально находятся эти аватарки.

Comment: По ссылке видите картинку? https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBSWM.jpg

Comment: @CrazyElf по ссылке вижу, а на stackoverflow нет...

Comment: @КостяГалга Ну не знаю, это что-то с браузером. Попробуйте кэш браузера почистить

Comment: Хорошо бы проверить с других браузеров/устройств/сети. В приватном режиме еще как вариант.